# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

Why do I get this error?

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; 3: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

this is my code:
I specifically made the index a string so there should be no problem, but my StatusMap variable gives me this red flag..

```
 const getStatusMeaning = (index: string) => {
    const StatusMap = {
      '0': 'Unknown',
      '1': 'Pending',
      '2': 'Success',
      '3': 'Failure',
    }

    return StatusMap[index]
  }
```

Comment: You're accept `"hello"` is a valid index. What do you think `StatusMap["hello"]` would produce? Certainly not any of these values, hence TS downgrades it to "any" (or upgrade, depending on how you look at it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to @Paleo answer, If you want a strongly typed method, I would recommend the following :

```
const StatusMap = {
  '0': 'Unknown',
  '1': 'Pending',
  '2': 'Success',
  '3': 'Failure',
};

const getStatusMeaning = (index: keyof typeof StatusMap): string => {
  return StatusMap[index];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define the proper type for `index`:

```
const getStatusMeaning = (index: '0' | '1' | '2' | '3') => {
  // Your implementation here
}
```

Or, use a [dictionary type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures) `{ [key: string]: string }`:

```
const getStatusMeaning = (index: string) => {
  const StatusMap: { [key: string]: string } = {
    '0': 'Unknown',
    '1': 'Pending',
    '2': 'Success',
    '3': 'Failure',
  }

  return StatusMap[index]
}
```

Comment: Note that `getStatusMeaning('invalid key')` won't display any error using the second method

Answer (score 1):

If you account for the fact that some strings do not exists as keys in your status map you can let TypeScript know that your map is a string record:

```
const StatusMap: Record<string, string> = {
```

The other solution is to be more specific about the index and only allow the supported indexes instead of any string.